# How to add a character

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Item          Code
A             123456
B             123455
C             23457
D             123458
E             23459
F
```

The `Code` column must have 6 characters and I need to add '1' (for example, `23455` to `123455`) for those items with less than 6 characters.

How can I do it with SQL ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle?

Comment: What's the table schema? Are the items in the `Code` column integers or are they characters?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL & the Code column is character.

Answer (score 8):

```
Update table
    set Code = CONCAT( '1', TRIM( Code ) )
  where LEN( TRIM( CODE ) ) < 6
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server and assuming the Code column is a character data type, you can do the following

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Code = '1' + Code
WHERE LEN(Code) < 6
```